# I want to make a binary search using linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIAFB.png)

Search Techniques
Use appropriate variable names and adhere to coding standards.
Handle user input and display output clearly.
Use iterative/recursive binary search in binary Search method
Submit the Java file (StudentName_BinaryLinkedList.java) containing your implementation. Replace student name with your name

Question at position 1
1

10 points

Question at position 1
You are given a sorted singly linked list of integers, and you are required to implement a binary search algorithm to find a target value within the linked list. Write a Java program that includes the following:

Define a class named Node to represent a node in the linked list. The class should have an integer value and a reference to the next node.

Define a class named Linked List to represent the linked list. The class should have methods to insert nodes and a method named binary Search that takes a target value as a parameter and returns true if the target value is present in the linked list, and false otherwise. Implement the binary search algorithm for linked lists.

In the main method, create an instance of the Linked List class and insert at least 10 sorted integers into the linked list. Prompt the user to input a target value to search for in the linked list. Call the binary Search method to determine if the target value is present and display the result.

This is what I tried and I get the same error

https://replit.com/@JordanBrown24/CS114#Main.java

```
public class Main
{ 
  class Node
  {
      int data;
      Node next;
      Node(int d)
      {
          data = d;
          next = null;
      }
  }

  class LinkedList
    
  {
      static Node push(Node head, int data)
      {
          Node newNode = new Node(data);
          newNode.next = head;
          head = newNode;
          return head;
      }
      static Node middleNode(Node start, Node last)
      {
          if (start == null)
              return null;

          Node slow = start;
          Node fast = start.next;

          while (fast != last)
          {
              fast = fast.next;
              if (fast != last)
              {
                  slow = slow.next;
                  fast = fast.next;
              }
          }
          return slow;
      }
      static Node binarySearch(Node head, int value)
      {
          Node start = head;
          Node last = null;

          do
          {

              Node mid = middleNode(start, last);
              if (mid == null)
                  return null;
              if (mid.data == value)
                  return mid;
              else if (mid.data > value)
              {
                  start = mid.next;
              }
              else
                  last = mid;
          } while (last == null || last != start);

          return null;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          Node head = null;

          head = push(head, 2);
          head = push(head, 5);
          head = push(head, 7);
          head = push(head, 11);
          head = push(head, 15);
          head = push(head, 18);
          int value = 7;

          if (binarySearch(head, value) == null)
          {
              System.out.println("Element not found");
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Element found");
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Binary search for linked list makes no sense. They don't belong together. This is not a good code challenge.

Comment: Please edit the question to include an exact copy of any error(s) you are getting. To ensure accuracy, use text copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- You are trying to access `Node` from a static context, but `Node` is not static
- As you don't create a `Main` *instance*, `Node` and `LinkedList` classes should be defined as static (unless you create them as top-level classes).
- You should define *instance* methods. For instance, it is not best practice to define `push` as a static method where you need to provide the head node as argument. Instead `push` should be an instance method.
- `head` should be an instance field of the `LinkedList` class, not a variable in `main`.
- The main function should create a `LinkedList` instance.

Here is your code with these remarks taken into account:

```
public class Main
{ 
    static class Node // Mark as static, since we don't create a Main instance
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    static class LinkedList  // Mark as static
    {
        Node head = null; // Should be a field, not a function argument
      
        Node push(int data) // Should not be static
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(data);
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
            return head;
        }
      
        static Node middleNode(Node start, Node last)
        {
            if (start == null || start == last) // Also capture case of 1 node
                return start;

            Node slow = start;
            Node fast = start.next;

            while (fast != last)
            {
                fast = fast.next;
                if (fast != last)
                {
                    slow = slow.next;
                    fast = fast.next;
                }
            }
            return slow;
        }
      
        Node binarySearch(int value)  // Should not be static
        {
            Node start = head;
            Node last = null;

            do
            {
                Node mid = middleNode(start, last);
                if (mid == null)
                    return null;
               if (mid.data == value)
                    return mid;
                else if (mid.data > value)
                    start = mid.next;
                else
                    last = mid;
            } while (last != start); // Don't need to test last is null
            return null;
        }
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); // Should create instance
        list.push(2);  // Use the instance to push data
        list.push(5);
        list.push(7);
        list.push(11);
        list.push(15);
        list.push(18);
        int value = 18;

        if (list.binarySearch(value) == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element found");
        }
    }
}
```

On a final note, this code challenge is not teaching the right thing: binary search has no place in the world of linked lists. It isn't efficient there. A linear search makes much more sense when searching a linked list, and will often find a node faster than binary search will.